# Проверка введенного содержимого

Tags: python

Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил числа типа `float`, и в то же время мог ввести "-h" or "close". Как проверить введенную строку на содержание `float`?

```
st = raw_input('Enter float number: ')
```

Пробовал

```
if float(st.isdigit()) == True:
    ....
```

Но почему-то все равно, если ввожу, например, 34.12, он не проходит мое условие..(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
st = raw_input()

try:
    st = float(st)
except ValueError:
    print 'not float'
else:
    print 'float'
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

```
st = "1.23"
st.isdigit() -> False
float(st.isdigit()) -> 0.0
0.0 == True -> False
```

Попаданий в `if` не будет.

Что делать? Писать просто float(st) и ловить исключение в случае если число не float

```
try: float(st)
except: if st in ( "-h", "close") : # обработать комманды, иначе сказать что введенные данные не корректны
```

Comment: благодарю, разобрался)